# Sorting a jagged array in C# by multiple columns

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

I know there's been a lot of questions and answers but neither applies to my problem. I have a jagged array that I'd like to sort by the values in array b, c and d:

```
string[][] toBeSorted = new string[][] { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j};
```

This only sorts by "rows"

```
toBeSorted = toBeSorted.OrderBy(inner => inner[2]).ToArray();
```

I have tried `Array.Sort(c.ToArray(), b)` and similar approaches but they mixed the whole selection in case of multiple valued sorting

So now when I have values in `toBeSorted` like "John", "Smith", "New York", etc.
I'd like to have my array sorted by the "cities", "surnames" and for example by the values in array `g` at last. So the values are a = names, b = surnames, etc.

I am .NET 3.5 dependent in my scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide some *examples*? Do you want to sort values within `b`, `c`, `d` arrays?

Comment: Your question is not very clear - in your example "John" and "Smith" are two different arrays? what does it mean to be sorted by surname when you only have strings in your array?

Comment: It seams that each array represents some data that should sit in a class with properties.. Is that the case?

Comment: Hi @DmitryBychenko, that would do it, but the thing is I'd like to keep the other related values "linked" together. So if I sort the b,c,d arrays, the other values from a, e, f, g, h, i and j would be rearranged as well - but only b, c, d need to be sorted.

Comment: @GiladGreen, might be a way to do it, yes.

Comment: @barakcaf, yes they are different arrays, correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `string[][]` where each item in the inner array actually represents a different "tag" of data create a proper class with the properties being those "tags":

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "A", LastName = "1", City = "B" },
    new Person { Name = "B", LastName = "3", City = "B" },
    new Person { Name = "C", LastName = "2", City = "B" },
};

//Linq OrderBy:
var result = people.OrderBy(p => p.LastName);

//List Sort:
people.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.LastName, y.LastName));
```

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot - my last question is (a little odd) - how do I extract the values from the sorted var now? from the `result` variable?

Comment: @baron - what do you mean extract results? It is a collection so you can iterate it

Comment: as an example when I'd like to do: `foreach (var i in result) { objWriter.WriteLine(i.LastName);}` ..nothing is written in the output file.

Comment: That is to do with the writing to the file itself that you are missing something. If you just `foreach` and print to `Console` you will see it is fine

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help ;) ..I'll look deeper into it then.

Answer (score 3):

Follwing @GiladGreen answer, you could achieve the same without creating the new classes, using anonymous types (assuming the data is uniformly formatted):

```
var people= toBeSorted.select (p => new {Name = p[0], LastName = p[1], City = p[2]});

var sorted = people.OrderBy(p => p.LastName);
```